# Programmatically remove a row from a GridLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to programmatically remove a row from a GridLayout?
The layout below consists of 3 rows (phone, cell, email).
In the code it can determine if there is no cell phone number. If not then I don't want to display the 2nd row at all.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<GridLayout xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/individual_gridlayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
    android:columnCount="4"
    android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
    android:rowCount="3">


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/phone_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_phone_enabled" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/voip_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_voip_enabled" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phone_number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:text="My Phone number"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small"
        tools:text="phone" />


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/message_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_textsms_enabled" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cell_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_phone_enabled" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/voip2_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_voip_enabled" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cell_number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:text="My Cell number"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small"
        tools:text="phone" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/email_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_email_enabled" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:text="someone@state.nm.us"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small"
        tools:text="email" />

</GridLayout>
```

Comment: Remove 3rd and 4th children or choose more suitable layout/widget

Comment: What would you suggest as a more suitable layout?

Comment: maybe TableLayout

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to solve this problem. What I've ended up doing is creating another layout file without the row in question and then based on some condition, choose the appropriate layout. Then in the code you also have to use this condition to dance around the components that may not be there.

```
if (some condition) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, container, false);
}
else {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout_no_cell, container, false);
}
```

mylayout_no_cell.xml

```
<GridLayout xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/individual_gridlayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
    android:columnCount="4"
    android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
    android:rowCount="2">


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/phone_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_phone_enabled" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/voip_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_voip_enabled" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phone_number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:text="My Phone number"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small"
        tools:text="phone" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/email_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_email_enabled" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:text="someone@state.nm.us"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small"
        tools:text="email" />

</GridLayout>
```

Comment: This answer was downvoted, and I get that this is not an optimal solution. I went with this because 1. The requirement for the ability to not display the row was after the fact and 2. Time was of the essence.

Answer (score 1):

Grid layout works with cells, not with rows, it gives you the cappability to change the amount of columns.
It will be more suitable to remove the undesired cells using something like:

```
GridLayout grid = findViewById(R.id.grid);
Button btnInGrid = findViewById(R.id.someButtonInsideTheGrid);
grid.removeView(btnInGrid);
```